# Given a proper homogeneous ideal, is there always a homogeneous maximal ideal that contains it?

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, graded-rings

It is known that every proper ideal of a ring must be contained in a maximal ideal, by the Zorn's lemma. Is this true in general for proper homogeneous ideals in a graded ring?

Comment: To be clear, by "homogeneous maximal ideal" do you mean an ideal that is both maximal and homogeneous or an ideal that is maximal among homgeneous ideals?

Comment: I also feel confused about this.

Comment: Perhaps I mean the maximal ideal which corresponds to a point in a projective variety.

Comment: What kind of graded ring are you interested in? Just, say, $\mathbb{C}[x_0,\dotsc,x_n]$ with standard grading (by total degree)? More general (arbitrary grading group, etc.)? If you just want $\mathbb{C}[x_0,\dotsc,x_n]$ then, pretty trivially, every homogeneous ideal is contained in the "irrelevant ideal" $(x_0,\dotsc,x_n)$ which is maximal, homogeneous, and maximal homogeneous. Note that, if $P \in \mathbb{P}^n$ is a point in projective space then $I(P)$ is **not** a maximal ideal.